# Infopath - Populating textbox from a SharePoint list datasource but newlines are stripping out

Tags: textbox, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

As the title indicates I'm populating an Infopath textbox control using a SharePoint list as a datasource. Unfortunately although there are carriage returns in the text in the SharePoint list it's stripped out of the textbox for no conceivable reason. I've tried numerous controls and a heap of google suggestions but come up short... has anybody encountered this before and know how to tackle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into the Tex Box properties and checking the Multi-line box.